# Get highest high and lowest low from interval

Tags: sql

I have the entries below and I want to extract data to create OHLC candle for 15 min (Question is with SQL tag but I cannot create new tags).
So i want for each 15 min i need highest high_price lowest low_price first open_price and last last_price

```
last_price|high_price|low_price|buy_price|sell_price|volume|volumeCurrent|open_price|STIME
11.3789 11.381  11.3789 11.33   11.4213 4767947 0   11.381  2014-05-25 20:15:00.000
11.3789 11.381  11.3789 11.33   11.4213 4767947 0   11.381  2014-05-25 20:14:00.000
11.3789 11.381  11.3789 11.33   11.4213 4768170 0   11.381  2014-05-25 20:13:00.000
11.3789 11.3789 11.3789 11.33   11.3789 4768000 0   11.3789 2014-05-25 20:12:00.000
11.3789 11.3789 11.3789 11.33   11.3789 4767787 0   11.3789 2014-05-25 20:11:00.000
11.392  11.31   11.392  11.33   11.4213 4767897 0   11.31   2014-05-25 20:10:00.000
11.392  11.392  11.37   11.33   11.392  4767643 0   11.37   2014-05-25 20:09:00.000
11.37   11.37   11.37   11.31   11.37   4767633 0   11.37   2014-05-25 20:08:00.000
11.37   11.3112 11.37   11.31   11.4213 4767633 0   11.3112 2014-05-25 20:07:00.000
11.37   11.37   11.37   11.31   11.37   4767642 0   11.37   2014-05-25 20:06:00.000
11.37   11.37   11.37   11.31   11.37   4767631 0   11.37   2014-05-25 20:05:00.000
11.33   11.37   11.33   11.33   11.37   4767620 0   11.37   2014-05-25 20:04:00.000
11.33   11.3149 11.33   11.31   11.4213 4767617 0   11.3149 2014-05-25 20:03:00.000
11.33   11.3149 11.33   11.31   11.4213 4767655 0   11.3149 2014-05-25 20:02:00.000
11.33   11.33   11.33   11.33   11.4213 4767386 0   11.33   2014-05-25 20:01:00.000
11.331  11.332  11.331  11.331  11.4213 4763363 0   11.332  2014-05-25 20:00:00.000
```

I tried something like this. Problem is that is getting me last high_price and last low_Price while I need highest **high_price** and lowest **low_price** from that 15 mins. Probably I need to use **max(highprice)** **min(lowprice)** but I don't know how.

```
SELECT 
        last_price,
        high_price,
        low_price,
        buy_price,
        sell_price,
        volume,
        volumeCurrent,
        open_price,
        date
FROM 
    m_cPrice 
WHERE 
    DATEPART(MINUTE,date)%15=0 and curency = '6'
ORDER BY 
    date desc
```

Comment: are you saying that you want the higest and lowest for each 15 minute interval or just this set of data which is for 15 minutes?

Comment: Yes but actually for each 15 min i need highest high_price lowest low_price first open_price and last last_price

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    MAX(high_price),
    MIN(low_price)
FROM m_cPrice
WHERE ...
```

With this query `ORDER BY` can be skipped, because of implicit grouping by `MAX()` and `MIN()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT min(date) as dt, max(high_price), min(low_price)
FROM m_cPrice 
WHERE currency = '6'
GROUP BY (DATEPART(MINUTE,date) / 15)
ORDER BY min(date) desc;
```

The `group by` takes the minute part and divides by 15.  SQL Server does integer division, so this should be a number from 0 to 3.